# $(this) is not giving the dom element for this javascript autocomplete function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the id/class of the element... but in the first case it is not coming.
Please tell me how can I get the current element id/class. $(this) is not working here.
In the first case the row_num value is coming undefined whereas in the second case the value can be obtained.
Please help.

```
    (function() {        
    $(".searchProduct").autocomplete({source: function( request, response ){
             var row_num = $(this).attr('data-rownum'); // need the value here
             var product_ids =  $(".thisweekwt_"+row_num).val();
            console.log(row_num); // value is undefined
            $.ajax({url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'search_auto')); ?>",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {q: request.term, product_ids},
                success: function( data ) {
                    response(data);              
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var id = ui.item.id;
            var price = parseInt(ui.item.title);
            var weight = ui.item.id;
            var table_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var key_num = $(this).attr('data-keynum');
            var row_num = $(this).attr('data-rownum');
            var key = row_num+"_"+key_num;
            var text_box_id = $(this);
            var row = document.getElementById(table_id);
              $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'month_box_push')); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id:id, key:key, row_num:row_num},
                success: function (response) {
                    var num = parseInt(key_num) + 1;
                    text_box_id.attr("data-keynum", num); 
                    newRow = response;
                    $(row).before(newRow);
                    var this_box_price = adding_box_price(row_num);                        $("#box"+row_num).text("Rs."+this_box_price);console.log(row_num); // value is defined                        $('#thisweekid_'+row_num).val($('#thisweekid_'+row_num).val()+","+id);
                    var this_box_wts = adding_box_pro_wt(row_num);
                    $(".thisweekwt_"+row_num).val(this_box_wts);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
            return false;   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: in the `source()` method, `this` does not refer to the same element as `this` or `ui.item` in the `select()` method. It's going to be difficult to assist in this case without knowing where the data-rownum attribute should be - based on your use of it in `select()` it is defined on the items (`<li>` elements) in the autocomplete suggestion list - but if that is the case there is no good way for you to access that data in `source()` - because those `<li>`'s don't exist yet then. You may need to add more of the contextual code.

Comment: Actually I was wrong about the value of `this` - in `source()` it is the jQuery widget instance, in select it is not, as I had thought, the selected element, but rather the text input on which autocomplete was initiated. if you just have the one `$('.searchProduct')` element on your page (and I am correct in assuming this is where your attribute lives), you can change the code in `source()` to `$('.searchProduct').attr('data-rownum');` and should be able to access the value. If you have multiple, you'll need to do something more complex.

Comment: Ya.. I have multiple usage and hence I need it dynamically so I can't use the id or class to get the attribute or values. Please suggest what u meant by saying doing something more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ui.item](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

```
select: function(event, ui) {
   var $this = ui.item;
   // the rest of you adapted code
}
```

Comment: Hey, I need to send the details in the data of the first ajax. My problem lies there where the value is coming undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a swing - by iterating through each of the `.searchProduct` elements, you can refer to them specifically in the callbacks you provide when initializing autocomplete on them.

```
(function() {        
    $(".searchProduct").each(function(){
        var $searchEl = $(this);
        $searchEl.autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ){
                 var row_num = $searchEl.attr('data-rownum'); // need the value here
                 var product_ids =  $(".thisweekwt_"+row_num).val();
                console.log(row_num); // value is undefined
                $.ajax({url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'search_auto')); ?>",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {q: request.term, product_ids},
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response(data);              
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                var id = ui.item.id;
                var price = parseInt(ui.item.title);
                var weight = ui.item.id;
                var table_id = $searchEl.parent().parent().attr('id');
                var key_num = $searchEl.attr('data-keynum');
                var row_num = $searchEl.attr('data-rownum');
                var key = row_num+"_"+key_num;
                var row = document.getElementById(table_id);
                  $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'month_box_push')); ?>",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {id:id, key:key, row_num:row_num},
                    success: function (response) {
                        var num = parseInt(key_num) + 1;
                        $searchEl.attr("data-keynum", num); 
                        newRow = response;
                        $(row).before(newRow);
                        var this_box_price = adding_box_price(row_num);
                        $("#box"+row_num).text("Rs."+this_box_price);
                        console.log(row_num); // value is defined
                        $('#thisweekid_'+row_num).val($('#thisweekid_'+row_num).val()+","+id);
                        var this_box_wts = adding_box_pro_wt(row_num);
                        $(".thisweekwt_"+row_num).val(this_box_wts);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
                return false;   
            }
        });
    })
});
```